# Spark - Best way agg two values using ReduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark, I have a pair `RDD[(String, (Int, Int)]`.  I am trying to find the best way to show multiple sums per key (in this case the sum of each `Int` shown seperately).  I would like to do this with `reduceByKey`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("foo", (1, 10)), ("foo", (2, 2)), ("bar", (5, 5))))
val res = rdd.reduceByKey((p1, p2) => (p1._1 + p2._1, p1._2 + p2._2))
res.collect()
```

Comment: Note collect will retrieve the results to your driver and may not be the best way to proceed if the RDD is very large. Consider `res.take(10)`

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @huitseeker I know. It wasn't supposed to be production code, just a snippet you could paste into the shell and check it works. :)